# Tab stop order for controls residing inside Tab control?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In my MFC application, which is a modeless dialog by itself, has a Tab control along with many other controls. And Tab control has two tabs, and dialogs are inserted into those.

This tab control is preceded and followed by other controls in the tabbing order. And when tab key gets to the tab control, It doesn't go into the dialogs inside tab, instead it moves to the next control in the application. I want that to go into the tab dialog and navigate through controls inside it.

At the moment, Tab key visits these dialogs inside tabs after visiting all controls in my application(modeless dialog).

How do I or where do I set tab order such that the tab key goes into the tab control dialogs ?

Comment: I have explicitly used `SetWindowsPos()` on controls inside tab dialogs to gain tab focus after tab key reaches the tab, but for no use.

Answer (score 1):

Research the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT window style. MSDN:

"If this style is specified, the dialog manager recurses into children of this window when performing navigation operations such as handling the TAB key, an arrow key, or a keyboard mnemonic."

Comment: I have this style on my application (modeless dialog) and DS_CONTROL on my tab control dialog already. Prior to adding these styles I wasn't able to get to the tab control dialog at all..